# Where is the LEGO logo on the Tartan Batman minifigure’s cowl piece?

Tags: piece-information

I was examining the cowl piece to my latest Batman mini-figure (the Tartan Batman from that came with the Batman movie magazine by Egmont) and I noticed that I don’t seem to be able to find the spot where the Lego logo is.

The outside is definitely clean, but could it be somewhere within the cowl, especially on the inner side walls? Because the slot where the top of the minifigure head would slot into is clean as well. Where could the elusive logo be? Anyone who knows please enlighten me!

Comment: Not all lego parts have the lego logo on them. Is there any reason you think this one should have a logo on it ?

Comment: I don't have a cowl around to check, but I guess it's big enough that they have placed it somewhere, but in most cases it's part of the mould, not printed on.

Answer (score 11):

Not printed, but molded, inside the left ear. Perhaps. I haven't checked that one in particular, because mine are unopened to give as gifts. But I do have others.

This cowl was relatively easy to see:

[image: cowl 1]

[image: cowl 1]

This cowl I initially thought didn't have one, but then I went back and looked with better equipment:

[image: cowl 2]

[image: cowl 2]